# Bootstrap User Data for ECS Container Instances for Mounting EFS storage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, amazon-efs

I am trying to Bootstrap ECS Container instances automatically so that every time an instance is launched it mounts the instance with the EFS storage.

I went to Cloud-formation stack for my cluster and tried to append my bootstrap script in the user data while updating the stack.
Following scripts are already present:

```
#!/bin/bashecho ECS_CLUSTER=flask-ecs >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config;echo ECS_BACKEND_HOST= >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config;
```

**Attempt1**
Bootstrap script(I inserted the commands which I used for manually mounting):

```
#!/bin/bashecho ECS_CLUSTER=flask-ecs >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config;echo ECS_BACKEND_HOST= >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config;sudo yum install -y amazon-efs-utils;cd /home/ec2-user/;mkdir efs;sudo mount -t efs fs-456665f:/ efs;
```

**Attempt2**
Bootstrap script(Added with reference to the Documentation [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/mount-fs-auto-mount-onreboot.html#mount-fs-auto-mount-on-creation))

```
#!/bin/bashecho ECS_CLUSTER=flask-ecs >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config;echo ECS_BACKEND_HOST= >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config;  #cloud-config repo_update: true repo_upgrade: all  packages: - amazon-efs-utils  runcmd: - file_system_id_01=fs-456665f - efs_directory=/home/ec2-user/efs  - mkdir -p ${efs_directory} - echo "${file_system_id_01}:/ ${efs_directory} efs tls,_netdev" >> /etc/fstab - mount -a -t efs defaults
```

Neither of the attempts mounted the EFS into the instances after logging into the instance. Now the container instances doesn't show up in the ECS cluster console.

Comment: can you login into the instance and please post the log gist of the file /var/log/cloud-init-output.log?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that you're using a YAML CloudFormation template and the only problem I see, is that the statement should be a multiline, like:

```
  UserData:
    "Fn::Base64": !Sub |
      #!/bin/bash
      echo ECS_CLUSTER=pidetodo-ecs >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config;echo ECS_BACKEND_HOST= >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config;
      sudo yum install -y amazon-efs-utils
      mkdir /home/ec2-user/efs
      sudo mount -t efs fs-456665f:/ /home/ec2-user/efs
```

This should be enough, and I'm not sure about using a bash script with cloud-init statements.  I would suggest to populate the /etc/fstab file first with the EFS filesystem information and then try the mount as the AWS document mentions.

Remember the 2 space indentation in the YAML.